# Is there a known fast algorithm for finding all pairs of numbers that multiply to a given number?

Tags: c#, algorithm

For example, the pairs that multiple to `16` are `{(16,1), (2,8), (4,4)}` and the pairs that multiply to `15` are `{(15,1), (5,3)}` but I'm not of how to construct an algorithm better than brute force. My method looks like

```
    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> Multipliers(int m)
    {
        var found = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach(int v in Enumerable.Range(1, m))
        {
            int d = m / v;
            bool even = m % v == 0;
            if(even && found.Contains(d))
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(d, v);
            }
            found.Add(v);
        }
    }
```

which is sloppy and probably not as efficient as possible.

Comment: Well, one easy optimization is to limit it to numbers from `2` to `m / 2`, since one multiple pair of `m` being `{m, 1}` is pretty obviously a given, and no number greater than `m / 2` (other than `m`) is going to be a multiple anyway.

Comment: If x*y = m and x <= y, then x <= sqrt(m). (It should be clear why you can assume that x <= y,)

Comment: The fact that it is hard to find factors (numbers that multiply a given number) is one of the things that many cryptography methods is based on. You may find this wikipedia page interesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample method for you, though I'm not sure if it's the "most efficient one", per se:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int A, int B)> Multipliers(int m)
{
    yield return (m, 1);

    int i = 2;
    int lastVal = m / 2;
    while (i <= lastVal)
    {
        if (m % i == 0)
        {
            lastVal = m / i;
            yield return (lastVal, i);
        }

        i++;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var pair in Multipliers(16))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.A, pair.B);
    }
}
```

Using C#7 tuple return syntax because I can. :P

**EDIT:** Switched from a `for` loop to a `while` loop to handle the case for when `m <= 2`.

**EDIT 2:** As suggested by Adwaenyth, this is a midified version of the method that checks if `m` is even. If not, then skip all even potential factors. Also, as suggested by other answers, limit the iteration to the square root of `m` instead of `m/2`:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int A, int B)> Multipliers(int m)
{
    yield return (m, 1);

    int lastVal = (int)Math.Sqrt(m);
    int increment = (m % 2 != 0) ? 2 : 1;
    int i = (m % 2 != 0) ? 3 : 2;

    while (i <= lastVal)
    {
        if (m % i == 0)
        {
            lastVal = m / i;
            yield return (lastVal, i);
        }

        i += increment;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this is as efficient as this particular approach can go. To make it better, you would tweak it to check against all prime numbers and their multiples up to the square root of `m`. Ideally, you would do this against a look-up table, since a lot of the time you save by only comparing prime numbers would be lost while generating them. (For really large `m`s, it still comes out faster, though.)

**EDIT 3** I discovered that my previous code's use of `lastVal` was making the required time be a bit inconsistent as well as introducing a weird bug that made it sometimes forget to check larger factors. Here's an update that should fix those problems:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int A, int B)> Multipliers(int m)
{
    yield return (m, 1);

    int finalVal = (int)Math.Sqrt(m);
    int increment = m % 2 != 0 ? 2 : 1;
    int i = m % 2 != 0 ? 3 : 2;

    while (i <= finalVal)
    {
        if (m % i == 0)
        {
            yield return (m / i, i);
        }

        i += increment;
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of a method that can return multiple values is causing me cognitive dissonance

Comment: @user7127000 But just think of the applications! :D But in actuality, it's not returning multiple values. This is just syntactical sugar for returning a `Tuple` with some magic for referring to the items in the tuple by an identifier. (There's more to it under the hood, but that's the basic idea.)

Comment: Friendly reminder to anyone reading this: if you are using .NET version 4.6.2 or older, you need to install the `System.ValueTuple` Nuget package into your project before you can use tuple return syntax.

Comment: If it is not divisible by 2, you can skip all even numbers as well and so on. So you should only divide by primes and multiples of that prime if it was divisible by the prime.

Comment: @Adwaenyth The math involved is so trivial that I'm not sure you would actually save all that much time by implementing the checks to skip the even numbers. The prime numbers would help, but that would involve also generating the list of primes, and that might just be more work than my lazy face is willing to do right now. :P

Comment: @Abion47 For even numbers it's quite simple. Just check once `if(m % 2 == 0)` and if so, increment i by 2. For primes you will need to keep a list of primes, yes. But it is faster for large numbers. ;)

Comment: @Adwaenyth I already tried that and compared it to the original's time with `m == int.MaxValue` The difference was about a quarter of a second (~4.5 seconds on the original and ~4.2 on the even-omitting one). I mean, if you're going to be dealing with billions of iterations or more, then sure, but otherwise...

Comment: @Adwaenyth So in theory, the most efficient application would be one that checks the multiples using primes from a pre-existing lookup table that covers the entire range of `[2, m]` for all possible `m` (or up to `int.MaxValue` in my case, since as written the input is limited to the range of an `int`). No point in checking against even numbers in that case, since after 2, none of the primes are even. :P

Comment: I don't understand where the square root comes from, but you don't get some values if you do it that way. If the limit is `Sqrt(m)`, for m=6 you don't get `(2,3)`, which is a valid pair 

Comment: @ferc The square root limit comes from the fact that the largest multiple you need to factor os the square root of the number. Past that point, you get duplicate pairs. For example, for 36 you would calculate `36,1`, `12,3`, `9,4`, and `6,6`, with `6,6` representing the square root of 36 times itself. Past `6,6`, the next multiple pair would be `4,9`, which is just the reverse of the `9,4` pair that you already calculated.

Comment: @ferc That being said, it does appear there is a bug in that code that stems from the calculation of `increment` and `i`. For 6 specifically, the way `i` is calculated would result in the initial value being 3, which is higher than the square root of 6 and would cause the loop to exit prematurely. The bug with `increment` appears to make it sometimes skip odd factors of even numbers (which happened when I plugged in 36 earlier). As such, I'm editing in a fix for these issues.

Comment: @ferc Actually, scratch that. The issue was somehow the even number check implemented from edit 2 got reversed. The `m % 2 == 0` is supposed to be `m % 2 != 0`. (Incidentally, this also is the reason my multiples calculation of 36 from the previous comment omitted `18,2`.)

Comment: @Abion47 I see... thanks for explaining the `Sqrt` bit. It makes sense! Though it seems there are still missing pairs; I think it has to do with the fact that you're truncating `finalValue`... perhaps ceil it to account for the decimal part?

Comment: @ferc Do you have an example of a number with missing pairs? Also, the flooring is intentional. If the square root isn't a whole number, then the next lower whole number is the limit. Take 30 for example - the square root is ~5.47, so flooring the number makes the limit 5. If the square root was ceiled, the limit would be 6, which would cause `5,6` and `6,5` to both be returned.

Comment: @Abion47 No, I just realized I was testing the wrong code... The latest version does return all pairs :)

Answer (score 1):

First generate a list of primes up to the square root of input N you will have, for each prime p check if it divides N. If it does then N = N/p and repeat this recursively until all primes in list has have been exhausted or N/p = 1.

In the rare case of where no primes in list can divide the input, then your number is a prime. The only pairs are {(1, N), (N, 1)}. This should get more rare as your input increases exponentially.

For the other case count all the prime divisors and the times they occur. Finally find all combination of products of the primes up to square root of N, which will all be part of pairs that divide N.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do this is perform prime factorization algorithm. But you should note that it is very difficult area of mathematics. You can find articles in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactorizationAlgorithms.html

From sequence of prime numbers you can combine all possible pairs which form given number